# Check text document for the same lines

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a long text document, which contains a lot of FEN's (some chess notation), which looks like this:

3b4/8/8/4k3/4N1Kp/4P3/5P2/8 w - -

Is there any way to check if some of this appear twice in the document?

Comment: What exactly should appear twice?

Comment: I have given a very general answer below. However, if you want specific examples, etc., you consider [edit]ing your question to include additional details.

Comment: Do you only want to see the duplicated lines or remove them? Maybe with a batch script...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to check if some of this appears twice in the document?

The two basic approaches to this would probably be to either write a script or use a third-party tool to compare lines and return/highlight any relevant duplicates.

On Windows, Powershell and Python are arguably decent options for scripting this sort of thing (not too complex, decent at parsing text/text files). For third-party utilities, ports of (Linux) `sed` and `grep` exist on Windows as well.

If you aren't tied to the command line, a text editor like Notepad++ could also be an option, as you can highlight a selection of text and display the lines/line numbers they are found in (somewhat similar to `grep`).